# D3D11 shader signature validation with SV semantics

Tags: shaders, hlsl, directx11

I'm trying to figure out what the rules are for linking the outputs of one shader stage to the inputs of the next.  Since D3D11 does not have any error checking for linkage between shader stages, I have written some code to check them by comparing the `D3D11_SIGNATURE_PARAMETER_DESC` struct from each input and matching it to an output of the previous stage. The code for checking the signatures [is here](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/pull-request/333/dx11-validate-shader-signatures-debug-mode/diff).

This mostly works, except when there are certain special inputs to a stage that don't get passed from the previous stage. One example is the `SV_IsFrontFace` input to the pixel shader. Another example is the `SV_PrimitiveID` input to any stage *after* the vertex shader.

I've been googling and reading msdn.microsoft.com and so far it's totally unclear to me exactly how these special SV semantics work. In particular:

**Q1**. Does the ordering of them matter? Or must they occur *AFTER* all inputs that are passed in from the previous stage?

**Q2**. Some of these "special" SV values can be identified by looking at the `SystemValueType` field of the `D3D11_SIGNATURE_PARAMETER_DESC`. For example `SV_IsFrontFace` can be identified by checking if the `SystemValueType` field is `D3D_NAME_IS_FRONT_FACE`. However, what about `SV_GSInstanceID`? There doesn't seem to be a corresponding value in the `D3D_NAME` enumeration for that. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728724(v=vs.85).aspx

**Q3**. Is there a link where the rules for shader input parameter linkage is explained clearly?  Or better yet, code for validating shader signatures?

Comment: D3D11 does have error checking.  You just have to turn on the debug layer—then it will complain loudly about any mismatches of shader signatures.  Also, is the instance ID not just `D3D_NAME_INSTANCE_ID`?  As for ordering, AFAIK the order of outputs and inputs has to match, so any new `SV` inputs in a shader stage would indeed have to come at the end of the list.

Comment: @Nathan Reed thanks for the tip about the debug layer, I'll check that out.  I'm not sure if `SV_GSInstanceID` and `SV_InstanceID` are the same thing or not, but they seem like distinct semantics.

Answer (score 1):

So the short answer is to turn on the debug layer.  Thanks to @Nathan Reed for pointing that out.

I tested it out and verified that it does indeed detect when shader signatures are incompatible.  I also verified that new `SV` inputs to a shader stage must come last in the list of inputs.